# Update using apt-get failed: "Connection timed out"

Tags: rpi-update

I want to update my Raspberry Pi, but I was not successful. This is the message when I try to update my device:

```
> pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get update
     Errhttp://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy Release.gpg   Could not
    > connect to 111.111.11.11:8080 (111.111.11.11), connection timed out
    > Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy Release.gpg   Could not
    > connect to 111.111.11.11:8080 (111.111.11.11), connection timed out
    > Err http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy Release.gpg   Could not
    > connect to 111.111.11.11:8080 (111.111.11.11), connection timed out
    > Err http://repository.wolfram.com stable Release.gpg   Could not
    > connect to 111.111.11.11:8080 (111.111.11.11), connection timed out
    > Reading package lists... Done W: Failed to fetch
    > http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg 
    > Could not connect to 111.111.11.11:8080 (111.111.11.11), connection
    > timed out
    > 
    > W: Failed to fetch
    > http://raspberrypi.collabora.com/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Could not
    > connect to 111.111.11.11:8080 (111.111.11.11), connection timed out
    > 
    > W: Failed to fetch
    > http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Could
    > not connect to 111.111.11.11:8080 (111.111.11.11), connection timed
    > out
    > 
    > W: Failed to fetch
    > http://repository.wolfram.com/raspbian/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Could
    > not connect to 111.111.11.11:8080 (111.111.11.11), connection timed
    > out
    > 
    > W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
    > ones used instead
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like your networking isn't happy? Plugged in over Ethernet or wifi USB stick? Do you have bog-standard IP addressing over DHCP i.e. you have a home hub that automatically allocates IP addresses? Can you access the internet from your hub through the browser?

Comment: Did it work before? Do other network connections work? Maybe the repo is just down now and it will work again in an hour or two.

Comment: @sarin Plugged in over wifi USB stick and i have a statick IP addresses. Also i can ping to google.com and access the internet from the browser

Comment: @Ghanima Yes, it worked but in 2 days didn't work.

Comment: If your pi is plugged in and you can ping external addresses successfully then the issue feels like it's external. Although the error messages seem suspicious as all the sites are resolving to the same odd IP address despite having different domains. I would try hardwiring your ethernet and running the update just to rule out any wifi/usb issues (although they are unlikely given you can ping external hosts)

Comment: I tried to hardwiring to ethernet and running and saw this message: "E:Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) E:Unable to lock directory /var/lib//apt/list"

Comment: Edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and insert two lines at the top: `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4` ([see here](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) about that).  "111.111.11.11" seems like a bogus value indicating a DNS resolution problem, using the google servers may correct that.  You should add some details about the context here.  Is this a regular home LAN with a normal ISP, or something else?

Comment: @goldilocks i have already use google dns.This is a regular home LAN.

Comment: @gulyvz Is the issue solved? I'm curious what the problem was.

Answer (score 3):

Find out if you have a proxy server configured for APT (you output looks as if you are trying to use 111.111.11.11 as a proxy):

- In `/etc/apt/apt.conf` there may be something looking like this: `Aquire::http::Proxy:: "http://111.111.11.11:8080/";`
- In the shell, you may find `export http_proxy=http://111.111.11.11:8080` in one of the following files:

  ```
  /etc/environment
  /etc/profile
  /etc/profile.d/*
  ~/.bashrc
  /root/.bashrc
  ```

If you find a proxy config somewehere, make sure that it is up and forwariding connections. Remove the proxy configurations if you can access the external server directly

Comment: This an interesting theory (+1), but I don't think raspbian would have configured [this IP](http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/111.111.11.11) as a proxy.  It could be some kind of problem with DNS resolution.

Comment: DNS would be another possibility. In this case, the port 8080 points straight toward „web proxy“ as a keyword and any IP address containing several „1“ digits may come up as proxy/hotspot/web gateway address. Thinking about it, this may also be a web gateway that redirects web access to a web page with a form to authenticate the IP address. It would then allow direct WWW access after the authentication has been done.

Comment: Maybe you are right after all: Looks like the owner of the IP (KDDI, a Japanese telecommunications corp.) hosts [a mirror for fedora](https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/), so they could be involved with debian or raspbian as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is either a proxy or DNS issue.

- Try: `nslookup mirrordirector.raspbian.org` or if `dnstools` is not
  installed, try `ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org` and see what it
  resolves to.
- If it resolves to `5.153.225.207` it isn't a DNS problem, if it
  doesn't, something is messing with DNS.
- If that doesn't narrow it down, try `wget

  http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/favicon.ico` output should be
  like:

> --2016-09-12 10:05:45--  http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/favicon.ico Resolving
>   mirrordirector.raspbian.org (mirrordirector.raspbian.org)...
>   5.153.225.207, 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 Connecting to mirrordirector.raspbian.org
>   (mirrordirector.raspbian.org)|5.153.225.207|:80... connected. HTTP
>   request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 1150 (1.1K)
>   [image/vnd.microsoft.icon] Saving to: `favicon.ico'
>
> 100%[===========================================================================>] 1,150       --.-K/s   in 0s
>
> 2016-09-12 10:05:50 (9.54 MB/s) - `favicon.ico' saved [1150/1150]

- If there is a proxy, you will see a redirect here or some sort of
  weirdness.
- If neither of those narrow things down, try adding some other
  mirrors: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

set to:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi firmware
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://mirror.umd.edu/raspbian/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://reflection.oss.ou.edu/raspbian/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

and try `sudo apt-get update` again.